# Remove part of the text in each file

Tags: php

I need to remove part of thet text starting with `</div></div></div>` and everything that goes after it in each file that is in temp dir. 
text stucture is basically the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

blah blah lots of text....

</div></div></div>

blah blah lots of text....

</div>

</html>
```

what i did:

```
$files = scandir(__DIR__ . "/temp/");
$files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));

foreach($files as $file) {

    $text_file = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/temp/".$file);

    foreach($text_file as $txfile) {

        $txfile = strstr($txfile, '</div></div></div>', true);
        echo $txfile;
    } 
}

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

and tried this way

```
$files = scandir(__DIR__ . "/temp/");
$files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..'));

foreach($files as $file) {

    $text_file = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/temp/".$file);

    for($i=0;$i<count($text_file);$i++)
    {

        $text_file = strstr($text_file[$i], '</div></div></div>', true);
        echo $text_file;
    } 
}
```

even tried `strstr` files with `glob` but still without results.

Answer (score 1):

In `$text_file = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/temp/".$file);`, `$text_file` will be a `string` not an `array`, so using `foreach` will throw an error.
You can try

```
foreach($files as $file) {

    $text_file = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "/temp/".$file);

        $txfile = strstr($text_file, '</div></div></div>', true);
        echo $txfile;
}
```